# Javascript: How to set 'this' to a object method

Tags: javascript

How can I get access to `this` in a object that is into a function like this:

```
function Foo (name) {
    this.name = name;

    var _ = {};
    _.bar = {};
    _.bar.print() = function () {
        return this.name;            // here I have access to the wrong this
    };

    this.print = function () {
        console.log(_.bar.print());
    };
}
```

Comment: There's a syntax error here

Comment: But maybe you want `_.bar.print = (function(){ ... }).bind(this)` ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kqmp0o7r/

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
_.bar.print() = (function () {
    return this.name;           
}).bind(this);
```

but the whole looks uselessly complex.

Comment: Thanks, that is it what I want. Yes I know that it looks complex, but at 1500 lines of code all looks complex.

Comment: What I mean is you might be using the wrong module pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Just save required `this` into a variable and use it in other scopes

```
function Foo (name) {
    var _this = this; // <-- store function's this
    this.name = name;

    var _ = {};
    _.bar = {};
    _.bar.print() = function () {
        return _this.name;            // use stored _this
    };

    this.print = function () {
        console.log(_.bar.print());
    };
}
```